# AudioKit 4.6 no sound

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I've been developing an iOS app the last year with AudioKit-4.0.4.  Now that I have the app working I thought it was time to update my AudioKit library to a newer version.

I have downloaded AudioKit-4.6 and merely swapped out the older "AudioKit For iOS.xcodeproj" in my XCode project with the new version.  Everything built just fine, except for AudioKit.start() now has to be wrapped with a "try".  No other changes were needed to get a successful build.

But now my app does not produce any sound.

Here is my code for starting AudioKit:

```
AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
mix = AKMixer()

AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
AudioKit.output = mix

do {
    try AudioKit.start()
    print("----- AudioKit Started -----")
} catch {
    print("Error AudioKit.start")
}

do {
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: AKSettings.SessionCategory.playback, with: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
} catch {
    print("Error setSession mixWithOthers")
}
```

In addition to no audio, I am seeing these repeated messages in the console log:

```
----- AudioKit Started -----
2019-04-08 15:03:45.709359-0700 HarmonicChimes[2708:2212995] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
2019-04-08 15:03:45.711236-0700 HarmonicChimes[2708:2212995] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
```

These AV messages show on my iOS 12 device but not iOS 11 and older.  Some googling on the net indicates these AV messages are Apple's problem, not AudioKit, but I was not seeing them when running with AudioKit 4.0.4.

The no sound problem is a show stopper! I have searched for "AudioKit no sound" but not found anything that makes sense.

It would appear that 4.6 is not just a simple plug-in replacement for 4.0?  Is there a new AudioKit api to get the sound started?  My app's plist and capabilities are set to allow for background operation, could that have something to do with this?

*(I am using XCode 10.1, macOS 10.13.6, and iOS 12.)*

Comment: I now have a simplified iOS demo app that demonstrates this problem.  When compiled with AudioKit 4.0.4 it works as expected.  When built with AudioKit 4.6 it fails to produce sound.  Shall I attach these two Xcode projects here?

Comment: That would be great @WholeCheese

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file to a thread in StackOverflow?  At any rate, I have uploaded "PlayTone-4.0.4.zip" to my web page.  It works fine under AK4.0.4.  Change it to AK4.6 and you will see (not hear) the no audio problem:  http://www.wholecheese.com/demos/

Comment: Oh, and yes, I have built a few of the AK4.6 sample apps and they do work for me.  This would indicate that there is something I am doing in 4.0.4 that is no longer supported in 4.6.  Please note that what I am doing in my PlayTone demo is based on what I learned from the samples that shipped in 4.0.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka  Have you had a chance to look at this?  I am basically stuck with AK 4.0.4 until this is resolved.  I would dearly love to update to AK 4.6 especially since I am now also trying to integrate Audiobus into my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the answer to this question in AudioKit's GitHub issues pages, but for the record here, it is just that AKOscillator was on by default in the past (bad) and has been fixed in the newest version. So, @WholeCheese has to add an osc.start() to his files. Next, I hope to do a screen share with him to solve the Audiobus issues.